# MecabをWindows10にインストール後、コマンドラインから使うと漢字だけが表示される

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, mecab, mingw

Linux Subsystem UbuntuのBashから`mecab`を起動すると正常：

```
nyck33@DESKTOP-9JIJ7R7:/mnt/c/Users/nick/Downloads$ mecab
面白い
面白い  形容詞,*,イ形容詞アウオ段,基本形,面白い,おもしろい,代表表記:面白い/おもしろい 反義:形容詞:つまらない/つまらない
EOS
```

MINGW64では分からない漢字が表示される：

```
$ mecab
面白い
面白い  險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
馬鹿だな
        險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
n       蜷崎ｩ・蝗ｺ譛牙錐隧・邨・ｹ・*,*,*,*
鹿だな  險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

Windows Command Promptでも同じく：

```
C:\Users\nick>mecab
面白い
面白い  險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

先ほどまでWindows Command Promptでは正常に動いていたのに、以下の説明でLinux Bashで使えるようにしたらこうなってしまいました。

[MecabをWindows Ubuntu Bashで使う方法](https://qiita.com/yukinoi/items/6475285c00f90e802b4b)

上記3つのShellで使える方法はありますか。それともWindows Linux Bashで使えるようにしたら他が駄目になってしまうものですか。助言をお願いします。

Edit:

こちら[WindowsでMecab-Python](https://qiita.com/fu23/items/34f55f0b7aaa7e2205b8)を参考にしてインストールしなおそうとしましたが、`python setup.py build`の時点で以下のエラーが発生しました：

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_MeCab' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MeCab\sdk" -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /TpMeCab_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\MeCab_wrap.obj
MeCab_wrap.cxx
MeCab_wrap.cxx(3052): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mecab.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

確認したら問題の`mecab.h`はありました：

[image: ファイルの保存先]

`\Anaconda3\Lib\site-package`には`MeCab.py`がありました：

[image: ファイルの保存先]

追加情報：

上記の現状のまま、ファイルからは正常に動作します。

```
$ python mecab-test.py
安倍    アベ    安倍    名詞-固有名詞-人名-姓
晋      ススム  晋      名詞-固有名詞-人名-名
三      サン    三      名詞-数
首相    シュショウ      首相    名詞-一般
は      ハ      は      助詞-係助詞
、      、      、      記号-読点
国会    コッカイ        国会    名詞-一般
で      デ      で      助詞-格助詞-一般
施政    シセイ  施政    名詞-一般
方針    ホウシン        方針    名詞-一般
演説    エンゼツ        演説    名詞-サ変接続
を      ヲ      を      助詞-格助詞-一般
行っ    オコナッ        行う    動詞-自立       五段・ワ行促音便        連用タ接続
た      タ      た      助動詞  特殊・タ        基本形
。      。      。      記号-句点
EOS
```

コマンドラインからは相変わらず異常です：

```
$ mecab
アイスクリーム
        險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
A       蜷崎ｩ・蝗ｺ譛牙錐隧・邨・ｹ・*,*,*,*
        險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
C       蜷崎ｩ・蝗ｺ譛牙錐隧・邨・ｹ・*,*,*,*
        險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
X       蜷崎ｩ・蝗ｺ譛牙錐隧・邨・ｹ・*,*,*,*
        險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
N       蜷崎ｩ・蝗ｺ譛牙錐隧・邨・ｹ・*,*,*,*
リ      險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
[       蜷崎ｩ・繧ｵ螟画磁邯・*,*,*,*,*
ム      險伜捷,荳闊ｬ,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく文字コードです。読み込みに利用しているファイルの文字コードと、実行時のLocaleのつじつまあっているか、確認してください。
Windowsコマンド環境では・・・・といいう話なので、ja_JP.UTF8でSJISのテキストを処理しようとしたりしてませんか？＜読み込み時に指定していないと大抵、ご提示の雰囲気の文字列に化けます。

Comment: 確認してみます。少しの間お待ちください。